# Django DRF routing not a valid regular expression

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to use a DRF viewset with an `@action` decorator, but when I call that endpoint I get the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 
"^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$" is not a valid regular expression: 
redefinition of group name 'format' as group 2; was group 1 at position 32
```

Here is `url.py`:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"", GenreViewSet, basename="genre")
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

And the `viewsets.py`:

```
class GenreViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    pagination_class = None
    queryset = Genre.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == "list":
            return GenreSerializer

    @action(detail=True, methods=["patch", "delete"], url_path="favourite")
    def make_genre_favourite(self, request, pk=None):
        genre = self.get_object()
        # Other code and responses here.
```

The parent url comes from `/api/genre/`. The `list` endpoint works, it returns all genres as it should, it's the action that gives that error.

Any help appreciated much. I've tried `format_suffix_patterns` and no luck in case you might be asking.

Comment: What's the actual URL that you're trying to match?

Comment: Think you mean this?
`url(r'^api/genre/', include('genre.urls')),`

Comment: no not this but the actual URL for which the above regex is giving error.

Comment: You can't have two capturing groups with the same name (`format`).  This has nothing to do with Django, that regex is broken on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing more research on this error, turns out it's pretty common and there are many ways why it could be caused by, it's mainly to do with with `format_suffix_patterns`. In the parent `urls.py` I had

```
urlpatterns = [
   path("api/", ...),
   # more paths,
]
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

For anyone coming across this, my fix was to remove `urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)` line.